# Redux Saga - Prevent "put" effect action from channel (take), when action was dispatched by a user

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga

My situation is the following:

There are several actions which changes my "Work" redux state, some of the actions are triggered by a user and one of the actions is triggered by push messages from socket.

I'm trying to find a mechanism that will cancel and/or prevent "updateWorkAction" action arriving from the socket to be handled, in case user's actions (takeLatest) are being triggered, but continue update the "Work" state if user's actions stack is empty.

```
import { fork, take, takeLatest, put, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';

function* socketWatch() {
    const socketPushChannel = yield call(socket.createChannel.bind(socket));
    while (true) {
        try {
            const message = yield take(socketPushChannel);
            if (message.type === 'someTest') {
                yield put(updateWorkAction());
            }
        } catch (error) {
            logger.warn('Push message failed with error: ', error);
        }
    }
}

function* workWatchers() {
    yield takeLatest(WorkTypes.UPDATE_WORK, updateWork); //should be conditionally ignored
    yield takeLatest(WorkTypes.ADD_WORK, addWork);
    yield takeLatest(WorkTypes.DELETE_WORK, deleteWork);
}

export function* rootWork() {
    yield fork(workWatchers);
    yield fork(socketWatch);
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify which action is supposed to be conditionally dropped inside of the `takeLatest`?

Answer (score 1):

I took a quick stab at this, though I am not entirely happy with the solution as it requires the `yield*` syntax, but I can't figure out better solution right now without having detached tasks, which has its own issues. But perhaps it can serve as an inspiration for something bit cleaner.

```
const takeLatestWithIgnore = (() => {
  const taskMap = new Map();
  return function* (pattern, ignoreOnDeps = [], saga, ...args) {
    const watcherTask = yield fork(function* () {
      try {
        while (true) {
          const action = yield take(pattern);
          const anyDepRunning = ignoreOnDeps.some((dep) =>
            taskMap.get(dep)?.isRunning()
          );
          // Here instead of continue you could buffer the ignored
          // action and run it somehow later
          if (anyDepRunning) continue;
          if (taskMap.get(watcherTask)) yield cancel(taskMap.get(watcherTask));
          const instanceTask = yield fork(saga, ...args.concat(action));
          taskMap.set(watcherTask, instanceTask);
        }
      } finally {
        taskMap.delete(watcherTask);
      }
    });
    return watcherTask;
  };
})();

function* workWatchers() {
  const addTask = yield* takeLatestWithIgnore(ADD_WORK, [], addWorkSaga);
  const deleteTask = yield* takeLatestWithIgnore(DELETE_WORK, [], deleteWorkSaga);
  yield* takeLatestWithIgnore(
    UPDATE_WORK,
    [addTask, deleteTask],
    updateWorkSaga
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you Martin, I will test your answer and update, could you please let me know why you are not happy with yield*? also, if a better solution jumps to your head, I would be very happy to hear.

Comment: Mostly because it is not used very often so people who don't know generators well can be confused & you need to think about this one specific case where it should be used. Also I have a feeling there is a simpler solution that I just don't see :D But it should do the trick.

Comment: I see, I got only one more question, while I implemented it I notice take(pattern, addWork); addWork is not recognize, which pattern should be there?

Comment: it should be only `take(pattern)`, fixed it in the answer ... sorry about that, thats what you get when you keep switching between effects while testing stuff O:)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on which code you need to work with specifically, but you can try some code like below - basically the first argument of `take` (and presumably `takeLatest`) just has to resolve to `true`

So you can try like below, assuming your action has a `payload`, you could pass `shouldBeIgnored` as a boolean inside of the `payload`.

```js
takeLatest(action => !action.payload.shouldBeIgnored, addWork);
```

Comment: I edited the question and commented the action that should might be ignored.
I have no problem distinguishing between the actions, I'm not sure how should I create the priority between the actions.